# Asterisk Digium TE110P

Tags: linux

I have Trixbox(Asterisk) with TE110P E1 card installed.
There is a question:
- is the TE110P driver capable to register ISDN PRI(E1) timing and slips errors ?

Which way the number of such errors can be measured ?

Alexey